# Using custom classes as keys in map

Tags: java, dictionary

What methods, if any, does a custom class need to implement in order to be used as a **key** in a `Map`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: hmm, key in Collection like `Map` might be everything (according to generic type). I don't think that you must override custom class

Comment: I think that i must override hashCode or equals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the kind of your map:

- Keys of `HashMap` must provide `hashCode` and `equals`
- Keys of `TreeMap` need to provide `compareTo` by implementing `Comparable<T>` unless the map is constructed with a `Comparator`, in which case there are no restrictions on the key itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a TreeMap your class will have to implement Comparable. If you are using a HashMap you will need a good hash function.